# Implementing a 2D, FFT-based Kernel Density Estimator in python, and comparing it to the SciPy implimentation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, kernel-density

I need code to do 2D Kernel Density Estimation (KDE), and I've found the SciPy implementation is too slow. So, I've written an FFT based implementation, but several things confuse me. (The FFT implementation also enforces periodic boundary conditions, which is what I want.)

The implementation is based on creating a simple histogram from the samples and then convolving this with a gaussian. Here's code to do this and compare it with the SciPy result.

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.stats import *
from numpy.fft import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from time import clock

ion()

#PARAMETERS
N   = 512   #number of histogram bins; want 2^n for maximum FFT speed?
nSamp   = 1000  #number of samples if using the ranom variable
h   = 0.1   #width of gaussian
wh  = 1.0   #width and height of square domain

#VARIABLES FROM PARAMETERS
rv  = uniform(loc=-wh,scale=2*wh)   #random variable that can generate samples
xyBnds  = linspace(-1.0, 1.0, N+1)  #boundaries of histogram bins
xy  = (xyBnds[1:] + xyBnds[:-1])/2      #centers of histogram bins
xx, yy = meshgrid(xy,xy)

#DEFINE SAMPLES, TWO OPTIONS
#samples = rv.rvs(size=(nSamp,2))
samples = array([[0.5,0.5],[0.2,0.5],[0.2,0.2]])

#DEFINITIONS FOR FFT IMPLEMENTATION
ker = exp(-(xx**2 + yy**2)/2/h**2)/h/sqrt(2*pi) #Gaussian kernel
fKer = fft2(ker) #DFT of kernel

#FFT IMPLEMENTATION
stime = clock()
#generate normalized histogram. Note sure why .T is needed:
hst = histogram2d(samples[:,0], samples[:,1], bins=xyBnds)[0].T / (xy[-1] - xy[0])**2
#convolve histogram with kernel. Not sure why fftshift is neeed:
KDE1 = fftshift(ifft2(fft2(hst)*fKer))/N
etime = clock()
print "FFT method time:", etime - stime

#DEFINITIONS FOR NON-FFT IMPLEMTATION FROM SCIPY
#points to sample the KDE at, in a form gaussian_kde likes:
grid_coords = append(xx.reshape(-1,1),yy.reshape(-1,1),axis=1)

#NON-FFT IMPLEMTATION FROM SCIPY
stime = clock()
KDEfn = gaussian_kde(samples.T, bw_method=h)
KDE2 = KDEfn(grid_coords.T).reshape((N,N))
etime = clock()
print "SciPy time:", etime - stime

#PLOT FFT IMPLEMENTATION RESULTS
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
c = contour(xy, xy, KDE1.real)
clabel(c)
title("FFT Implementation Results")

#PRINT SCIPY IMPLEMENTATION RESULTS
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
c = contour(xy, xy, KDE2)
clabel(c)
title("SciPy Implementation Results")
```

There are two sets of samples above. The 1000 random points is for benchmarking and is commented out; the three points are for debugging.

The resulting plots for the latter case are at the end of this post.

Here are my questions:

- Can I avoid the .T for the histogram and the fftshift for KDE1? I'm not sure why they're needed, but the gaussians show up in the wrong places without them.
- How is the scalar bandwidth defined for SciPy? The gaussians have much different widths in the two implementations.
- Along the same lines, why are the gaussians in the SciPy implementation not radially symmetric even though I gave gaussian_kde a scalar bandwidth?
- How could I implement the other bandwidth methods available in SciPy for the FFT code?

(Let me note that the FFT code is ~390x fast than the SciPy code in the 1000 random points case.)

[image: Three point debugging KDE using FFT.]
[image: Three point debugging KDE using SciPy]

Comment: for question 2 and 3 you best look at the scipy code. It uses the data covariance matrix and Scott's or Silverman's bandwidth rule.

Comment: I believe the above implementation shows an unconventional choice with respect to Kernel Density Estimation, e.g. check [Tarn Duong's explanation](http://www.mvstat.net/tduong/research/seminars/seminar-2001-05/); the main point is that you are not supposed to convolve a histogram but the original data (i.e. a comb of delta functions located at the data point).

Comment: Than again, as always -- I may be wrong; see [jakevdp's FFT-based-computation](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/#FFT-based-computation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences you're seeing are due to the bandwidth and scaling factors, as you've already noticed.

By default, `gaussian_kde` chooses the bandwidth using [Scott's rule.](http://books.google.com/books?id=wdc8Xme_FfkC&lpg=PP2&ots=kcKiNgFxf2&dq=scott%27s%20rule%20multivariate%20density%20estimation&lr&pg=PP2#v=onepage&q=scott%27s%20rule%20multivariate%20density%20estimation&f=false)  Dig [into the code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/kde.py#L430), if you're curious about the details.  The code snippets below are from something I wrote [quite awhile ago to do something similar](http://pastebin.com/LNdYCZgw) to what you're doing. (If I remember right, there's an obvious error in that particular version and it really shouldn't use `scipy.signal` for the convolution, but the bandwidth estimation and normalization are correct.)

```
# Calculate the covariance matrix (in pixel coords)
cov = np.cov(xyi)

# Scaling factor for bandwidth
scotts_factor = np.power(n, -1.0 / 6) # For 2D

#---- Make the gaussian kernel -------------------------------------------

# First, determine how big the gridded kernel needs to be (2 stdev radius) 
# (do we need to convolve with a 5x5 array or a 100x100 array?)
std_devs = np.diag(np.sqrt(cov))
kern_nx, kern_ny = np.round(scotts_factor * 2 * np.pi * std_devs)

# Determine the bandwidth to use for the gaussian kernel
inv_cov = np.linalg.inv(cov * scotts_factor**2)
```

After the convolution, the grid is then normalized:

```
# Normalization factor to divide result by so that units are in the same
# units as scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde's output.  (Sums to 1 over infinity)
norm_factor = 2 * np.pi * cov * scotts_factor**2
norm_factor = np.linalg.det(norm_factor)
norm_factor = n * dx * dy * np.sqrt(norm_factor)

# Normalize the result
grid /= norm_factor
```

Hopefully that helps clarify things a touch.

As for your other questions:

> Can I avoid the .T for the histogram and the fftshift for KDE1? I'm
>   not sure why they're needed, but the gaussians show up in the wrong
>   places without them.

I could be misreading your code, but I think you just have the transpose because you're going from  point coordinates to  index coordinates (i.e. from `<x, y>` to `<y, x>`).

> Along the same lines, why are the gaussians in the SciPy
>   implementation not radially symmetric even though I gave gaussian_kde
>   a scalar bandwidth?

This is because scipy uses the full covariance matrix of the input x, y points to determine the gaussian kernel.  Your formula assumes that x and y aren't correlated. `gaussian_kde` tests for and uses the correlation between x and y in the result.

> How could I implement the other bandwidth methods available in SciPy
>   for the FFT code?

I'll leave that one for you to figure out. :)  It's not too hard, though. Basically, instead of `scotts_factor`, you'd change the formula and have some other scalar factor. Everything else is the same.